# How to Change the colour of LED's with fastLED and a ESP32

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, fastled

so I developed an app which will send a series of integers over Bluetooth (for RED, GREEN & BLUE) to a ESP32 which will then change the colour of 3 LED's (WS2811) based on the numbers it receives. It works the first time I send them but when I try to change the colour of the LED's a second time nothing happens.

By using the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE I have verified that the numbers are being received by the ESP32 every time I send the numbers, but I cannot understand why the LEDs are not changing colour after the first send.

The code is as follows :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <fastled_config.h>

#define NUM_LEDS      3 // was 100
#define LED_TYPE   WS2811
#define COLOR_ORDER   RGB
#define DATA_PIN        4
//#define CLK_PIN       4
#define VOLTS          12
#define MAX_MA       4000
CRGBArray<NUM_LEDS> leds;

#define LED 2


int myRGB[30];
int counter =0;
int display =-1;



#include "BluetoothSerial.h" 


// init Class:
BluetoothSerial ESP_BT; 


// Parameters for Bluetooth interface
int incoming;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESP_BT.begin("ESP32_Control"); //Name of your Bluetooth interface -> will show up on your phone


  delay( 3000 ); //safety startup delay
  FastLED.setMaxPowerInVoltsAndMilliamps( VOLTS, MAX_MA);
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS)
    .setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
}

void loop() {


delay(1000);
Serial.println(myRGB[1]);
Serial.println(myRGB[2]);
Serial.println(myRGB[3]);

leds[0].r = myRGB[1];
leds[0].g = myRGB[2];
leds[0].b = myRGB[3];

leds[1].r = myRGB[4];
leds[1].g = myRGB[5];
leds[1].b = myRGB[6];

leds[2].r = myRGB[7];
leds[2].g = myRGB[8];
leds[2].b = myRGB[9];

FastLED.show();

  
  // -------------------- Receive Bluetooth signal ----------------------
  if (ESP_BT.available()) 
  {

    
    incoming = ESP_BT.read(); //Read what we receive 
digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

counter ++;
myRGB[counter] = incoming;

  if (counter > 29) counter = 0;
Serial.print("counter :" );
Serial.println(counter);
Serial.print( myRGB[counter]);
  

    
    }
  } // end loop
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the output from the serial monitor please. I'm not understanding what the line `if (counter > 29) counter = 0;` is doing. Should that be `9` rather than `29`?

Comment: Hi, yes it should be 9, although that shouldnt make any differnce to the operation of the LEDs. The output is just the numbers that have been sent over, which are correct. The key point here I think is that the LED's light up with the correct colour to start with but wont update when I re send some new colours although the serial monitor does show the updated numbers.

Comment: Can you explain why going beyond 9 would not make a difference? This is why I was interested in the output of the serial monitor because it outputs the value of the `counter`.  I'm assuming that the second time you send values the counter values would be 10 to 18  while the  LED code would still be reading from 1 to 9 and those values wouldn't have changed.

Comment: Going beyond 9 will not make any difference because the in the Array MyRGB the first number sent is always MyRGB[1] second number MyRGB[2] etc. The only reason it goes up to 29 is eventually I want to have 10 LED's (3 x 10) hence going up to 29 (0-29). I can't post the Serial monitor results at the moment because my laptop is down but I'll try it do it on another machine. Just to claify if I send a new lot of numbers the new numbers replace the old ones and these new numbers are shown in the Serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the LED colors are being shown before before Bluetooth inputs are received.

I would move `FastLED.show()` to the end of `loop()`.

```c
    FastLED.show();
} // end loop
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply.
Ok the following code works, it not really much different to the original code
apart from this :

`enter code here`if (counter < 9)
myRGB[counter] = incoming;

`enter code here` }

Which I'm guessing did make a difference (although it shouldn't have)

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <fastled_config.h>


#define NUM_LEDS      3 // was 100
#define LED_TYPE   WS2811
#define COLOR_ORDER   RGB
#define DATA_PIN        4
//#define CLK_PIN       4
#define VOLTS          12
#define MAX_MA       4000
CRGBArray<NUM_LEDS> leds;

#define LED 2


int myRGB[30];
int counter =0;
int displayCounter =-1;
 



#include "BluetoothSerial.h" 


// init Class:
BluetoothSerial ESP_BT; 


// Parameters for Bluetooth interface
int incoming;

void setup() {

  
Serial.println("ESP started !!");


  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESP_BT.begin("ESP32_Control"); //Name of your Bluetooth interface -> will show up on your phone


  delay( 3000 ); //safety startup delay
  FastLED.setMaxPowerInVoltsAndMilliamps( VOLTS, MAX_MA);
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS)
    .setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
    
}

void loop() {

delay(20); // WITHOUT THIS LINE MORE LIKELY TO GET INCORRECT DATA FROM BLUETOOTH

displayCounter ++;
if (displayCounter < 4){
  
  Serial.println("*****  the following values going into led[0] ( R G B )  *** ");
Serial.println(myRGB[1]);
Serial.println(myRGB[2]);
Serial.println(myRGB[3]);
Serial.println("*****  the following values going into led[1] ( R G B )  *** ");
Serial.println(myRGB[4]);
Serial.println(myRGB[5]);
Serial.println(myRGB[6]);

Serial.println("*****  the following values going into led[2] ( R G B )  *** ");
Serial.println(myRGB[7]);
Serial.println(myRGB[8]);
Serial.println(myRGB[9]);

}


leds[0].r = myRGB[1];
leds[0].g = myRGB[2];
leds[0].b = myRGB[3];

leds[1].r = myRGB[4];
leds[1].g = myRGB[5];
leds[1].b = myRGB[6];

leds[2].r = myRGB[7];
leds[2].g = myRGB[8];
leds[2].b = myRGB[9];
FastLED.show();

  
  // -------------------- Receive Bluetooth signal ----------------------
  if (ESP_BT.available()) 
  {

displayCounter = -1;
    
    incoming = ESP_BT.read(); //Read what we receive 
//digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);


counter ++;
  if (counter < 9)
  myRGB[counter] = incoming;
      
    }

else {counter = 0;
  // Serial.println("End of bluetooth data");
}



  } // end loop
```